# Adding powers of 2 to create unique integers

Tags: summation, integers

Is it true that if an integer $k$ can be represented as $2^a$+$2^b$+...$2^n$, where a, b ... n are the members of a finite subset of $N$, there is no other way to represent $k$ as a sum of powers of 2? how could I start to show that?

Comment: By $N$, do you mean $\Bbb N$ and is $a = b = \dots = n$ allowed?`

Comment: Hint: If $a\gt b\gt c\gt\cdots$ then your sum is $\ge 2^a$ and less than $2^{a+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true, otherwise your computer would not work, and you could not pot the question in this forum :)
$a, b, ..., n$ are different. You just want to see the binary representation of a positive integer. To prove uniqueness, it was already shown for example at [Binary expansion Unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99506/binary-expansion-unique?lq=1)

Comment: haha, i didn't even make the connection with binary! in retrospect this is extremely obvious, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here is an algorithm that will give you the decomposition for any fixed integer $k$.

```
i = 0
while k > 0:
   a[i] = k mod 2
   k = k div 2
```

After you are done, $$k = \sum_{i=0}^{|a|} 2^{a_i}$$