# Proof that the base 10 representation of a positive integer is unique

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proposition: Let n $\in$ N. If $n = \sum_{i=0}^{p} x_i10^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{q}y_i10^{i} $ where $p,q, \in Z_{\geq0}$, each $x_i$ and each $y_i$ is a digit, $x_p\neq0$ and $y_q\neq0$,

then $p=q$, and $x_i = y_i$ for all i

So far I have:

$n = \sum_{i=0}^{p} x_i10^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{q}y_i10^{i} $

$\sum_{i=0}^{p} x_i = \sum_{i=0}^{q}y_i $

$\sum_{i=0}^{p} x_i - \sum_{i=0}^{q}y_i = 0$

I feel like I can perform some summation algebra to write this as one summation, but I'm not sure how.

How do I prove that $p=q$ and the sequence $x_i = y_i$ ?

Comment: Proof by contradiction, find the first difference, show that its impossible.

Comment: Let $x = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{p}x_i10^i$ and $y=\sum\limits_{i=0}^q y_i 10^i$. To show $p=q$: supposing that $q > p$, can you work out the minimum possible value of $y$ and the maximum possible value of $x$ and hence show that $y > x$ (so $y\ne x$)? (It might help if you think in terms of specific numbers a bit: "clearly" a $4$ digit number is greater than any $3$ digit number for example, since a $4$ digit number is at least $1000$ and a $3$ digit number is at most $999$.)

Comment: This is a little confusing to me; I tried going along this path and I proved that the last term of each of the different sums, are unequal to each other. How does this help proving p = q and $x_i = y_i$?

Comment: As you well know, the proof won’t be too much good for *infinite* expansions. How were you planning to use it to get to the claim in your title ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017323/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-that-binary-expansion-is-unique/3017368#3017368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue with the base $10$ representation being unique is that the digits are restricted to being between $0$ and $9$ inclusive (note that without this limitation, the representations may not necessarily be unique). The main reason this is important is that the difference in digits is limited to being between $-9$ and $9$, inclusive. To see why this is important, consider what you've stated, i.e.,

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{p} x_i 10^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{q} y_i 10^{i} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

where $p,q, \in Z_{\geq 0}$, each $x_i$ & $y_i$ is a digit of $0$ to $9$, $x_p \neq 0$ and $y_q \neq 0$. To make it a bit easier for processing in case $p \neq q$, let $r = \max(p,q)$ and extend $x_i$ to be $0$ for any $i \gt p$ and $y_i$ to be $0$ for any $i \gt q$, so \eqref{eq1} becomes

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{r} x_i 10^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{r} y_i 10^{i} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Subtracting the middle & LHS parts of \eqref{eq2} gives

$$0 = \sum_{i = 0}^{r} \left(x_i - y_i\right) 10^i \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

If $x_i \neq y_i$ for one or more $i$, let $k$ be the smallest one. Thus, for all $i \lt k$, $x_i = y_i$ so $x_i - y_i = 0$, causing those terms to all become $0$. They can therefore be ignored, simplifying \eqref{eq3} to

$$0 = \sum_{i = k}^{r} \left(x_i - y_i\right) 10^i \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Next, dividing both sides by $10^k$ gives

$$0 = \sum_{i = k}^{r} \left(x_i - y_i\right) 10^{i - k} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Note that all of the terms on the RHS of \eqref{eq5} have at least one factor of $10$ except for the first one. Since $10$ divides $0$, plus all of the terms on the RHS of \eqref{eq5} after the first term, this means the first term of $\left(x_k - y_k\right)10^0 = x_k - y_k$ must be a multiple of $10$. Since $-9 \le x_k - y_k \le 9$, this means that $x_k - y_k = 0$, i.e., $x_k = y_k$, so they can't be different. This contradicts the assumption that there is at least one digit different, thus showing that all of the digits up to $r$ are the same. This also means the highest non-zero ones must be the same, i.e., $p = q$.

This same basic argument can be used to show that an integer can be uniquely represented in any base $b \ge 2$ as long as the digits used are in the range of $0$ to $b - 1$, inclusive (e.g., binary using $0$ and $1$, or hexadecimal using $0$ to $F$).

Comment: If $xi≠yi$ for one or more i, let k be the smallest one. Thus, all lower differences will be 0...
What do you mean by all the lower differences will be 0?

Comment: @beepbeepboop123123 Since $k$ is the smallest value of $i$ where $x_i \neq y_i$, then for all $i$ (if any) less than $k$, we have that $x_i = y_i$, so $x_i - y_i = 0$, i.e., the differences are $0$.

Comment: @beepbeepboop123123 I used the term "lower" to mean for all smaller indices, but that wasn't clear to you, so I've updated my answer to try to explain that section more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather the proving any two representations on $N$ must be equal, try proving $N$ has exactly one unique representation.

But the division theorem, for any integer $N$ the are are unique integers $M_1$ and $x_0$ so that $N = 10M_1 + x_0; 0 \le x_0 < 10$.  This proves that $x_0$ must be uniquely determined.

Inductively for each $M_k$ there are unique $M_{k+1}$ and $x_{k}$ so that $M_k = 10M_{k+1} + x_k; 0\le x_k < 10$.

And that's it really.  As $N$ is bounded above by some $10^{p+1}$ this will have a finite number of steps.