# How to prove that any positive integer can be written as sum of weighted powers of another number?

Tags: number-theory

I am hypothesizing the following result, given two natural numbers $n$ and $x$,  then there exists a unique sequence of coefficients $\{a_1,a_2...,a_n \}$ with $a_i $ in whole numbers such that:

$$ n= \sum_i a_i x^i$$

When $x=10$, this coincides with the standard form of numbers. How do I prove such a sequence exists always?

Edit: From the current answer I received and the comment, I put a further restriction $a_i <x$

A comment is that I think the reminiscent of how we prove that a vector has a unique decomposition into components given a complete basis.

Comment: This is not true. You need the set of coefficients to be bounded above strictly by $x$ for uniqueness.

Comment: Could you rephrase the last part @DonThousand

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167706/proof-that-the-base-10-representation-of-a-positive-integer-is-unique)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Comment: @Buraian Look at the answer provided on this question. It gives you a counterexample to uniqueness.

Comment: Hi Don, I think I accounted for it now. I saw your comment first before the answer.

Comment: One way is induction.  Prove that if it's true for naturals $< x^n$ then it's true for naturals $<x^{n+1}$.

Comment: This idea, using "radix notation" to express a large number as a polynomial evaluated at a smaller number, has an important application in setting up a [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) factoring project.

Comment: This got deep quite quickly haha. I will try go over the three links sent and attempt a self answer in time (if no one else writes a proof by then)

Comment: Hint: Just use the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You need further restrictions.
For example, in your example $10$ can be represented via $(10,0,0,0...,0)$ and via $(0,1,0,0,0....)$.

Comment: I've edited the question now.