# Division method for base-conversion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is an article called “The Base-Conversion method:Why does it work?” ([The Base-Conversion method:Why does it work?](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/base_why.htm)),which states that:

> Each time you divide, you're asking "Does the original number contain a multiple of this power of two?", and the remainder is either telling you "yes" (with a "0") or "no" (with a "1")”.

I have checked it on many examples and it really works,but I can not understand why.
Could you please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find an  answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017323/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-that-binary-expansion-is-unique/3017368#3017368

Answer (score 0):

When you write a number in base $2$ the non zero numbers are remainders in dividing by powers of two. For example $15$ is written as $1111$ that means if you divide it by two the remainder is one . $$15=2\times 7+1$$
Now if you divide $7$ by two the remainder is $1$ and so forth.